# HttpUrlConnection taking too long, why?

Tags: java, spring, http

i made a HttpUrlConnection GET in Java. And takes a lot to process, the code makes a GET to a URL that returns a JSON. (Which is not that huge, just a couple of rows) Don't know why is taking like A LOT to process from a jQuery ajax call client-side.

This is the Java code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getchartdata", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<String> graphChartData(ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request) {
        String graphName = request.getParameter("graphName");
        String subgroup = request.getParameter("subgroup");

        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        try {
            String configURL = EsbConfig.getProperty("graph.url", "http://localhost:8081");
            URL url = new URL(configURL + "/plot/get?graphName="+ graphName+"&subgroup="+subgroup+"&width=100");
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            String line = null;

            StringBuilder responseData = new StringBuilder();
            while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                responseData.append(line);
            }       
            HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
            responseHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            return new ResponseEntity<String>(responseData.toString(), responseHeaders, HttpStatus.CREATED);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if(null != connection) { connection.disconnect(); }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

I won't add the ajax call since it's pretty plane and simple, nothing to say about that.
If i access directly with the entire URL, i get the json response in nano seconds. If i make the call from client-side, it takes like 10 seconds to retrieve the info.

Any ideas on what's wrong? or any other HTTP get i could implement?

Thanks.

Comment: Any way to post links to the site so we could test it from this side?

Comment: Have you tried calling the ajax in different browsers to see if there is any difference?

Comment: Chrome and Firefox takes the same time :(

Comment: Tried accessing it from a different computer?

Comment: Careful when you are building your `responseData`. You are reading a line from the `BufferedReader` but aren't appending a new line character each time. `BufferedReader#readLine()` does not contain the end of line characters it finds. In this case, it's just json so it might not matter, but just **fyi**.

Comment: Add timing logging to the server code that processes `/plot/get`. Add timing logging to the `graphChartData` method. Add timing logging to your JS. See where most of the time is spent.

Comment: okey guys im going to do that and i will post it here again, thanks for your help !

Comment: LOL, it's not the java server-side code. It takes around 30 to 90 msecs to finish doing its task. So... this could be a problem of the client side??? o_O

Comment: I could solve it :) it was the setInterval function. Used setTimeout method.